# Why is photoshop not taking in my fonts?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I downloaded this psd file with fonts I did not have. That's fine. I looked at free font sites and found it. Once I downloaded it, it still has that exclamation mark next to the layer. I have the font within the brackets that it wants. I see it in my character panel...

It's not that big of a deal but I'd like to know what's going on.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you so anything with the files after you downloaded them? You have to install fonts on your system before they are active.

Comment: Yes, I dragged the font to the folder inside the control panel of windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A font that's a different type (OTF vs. TTF vs. Type 1) from the original will not be recognized as "the same" by an of the Adobe applications, even if the name is the same. If the name is the same but it's a different font from a different foundry, once again Photoshop will not agree that it's the same font. Even a different version of the same font will not be acknowledged.

The reason for this is that a different font file from the original can (and often will) cause text to reflow unexpectedly, which can be disastrous (consider a carefully set page layout where line breaks and spacing have been fine-tuned).

In your case, this may not be a big deal, so you can simply go into the Character Panel and change the layer font to the one you have installed. There may be a slight change in appearance, but you can adjust for it.

Comment: Thanks Alan for that info. If only there's a way to convert these files into a type that Adobe can understand...

Comment: That's like wishing for a way to "convert" a 2003 Toyota Camry to a 2005 Toyota Camry. The only way to do it is to get a 2005 model and replace everything in the 2003 with parts from the 2005. Since you already *have* a 2005 model, why would you bother?